# Escaping Quotes in Chef Bash

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra, cron, double-quotes

This I need quotes in a cronjob which I am creating through a chef recipe but even though I escape the quotes they do not appear in the cronjob which is created.

```
bash "Add cron" do
  user root
  group root
  code <<-EOH
      (
        (crontab -l; echo "5 0 * * * /bin/find #{node['user']['dir']}/files/ -type f \\( -name \"*.csv\" -o -name \"*.csv.bad\" -o -name \"*.ctrl\" \\) -mtime +1 -print0 | xargs -0 gzip -f" ) | crontab -
       )     
  EOH
end
```

just to clarify the cron job I want to end up with should contain `-name "*.csv"`

but what I actually get is `-name *.csv`

Comment: any reason to not use the `crontab` resource instead ?

Comment: I'm editing recipes that were created by someone else, this is just how they did it. I did consider using that instead but I assume I should be able to do what I'm trying to here.

Comment: The single quote echo argument and keep double quotes within. that's just a bash problem at all. But really, that's brittle and make very few sense when there's resources handling that properly for you already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bash "Add cron" do
  user "root"
  group "root"
  code <<-EOH
      (
        (crontab -l; echo -e '5 0 * * * /bin/find /home/root/files/ -type f \\( -name \"*.csv\" -o -name \"*.csv.bad\" -o -name \"*.ctrl\" \\) -mtime +1 -print0 | xargs -0 gzip -f'
       )
  EOH
end
```

Use single quote instead of double here.

Comment: my fault, i have edited the code in an attempt to simplify the case, i removed a section of it which already uses single quotes, i have edited the example again.

Comment: i suppose i can swap the attriute declaration quotes for doubles

Comment: you mean to swap quote as in'<attribute>' with quote in "<attribute>" ?, If this is what you ask then yes, double quotes is more specifically used when need to do string interpolation in attribute declaration.